# inserting multiple checkboxes into one column but in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I have a page with multiple checkboxes. My code inserts each checkbox into a separate column, although this is causing issues when I am looking to pull information out again.

I had previously been able to insert into one column but the answers all went into one field rather than separate rows. I also need the user_id of the user logged in to insert into each row for each box checked as well.

Can anyone please copy and amend my code to be able to insert into one column (response) and into separate rows, along with the user_id.

Here is my code, thank you

```
<?php  
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{  
header("Location: eNISATVids.php");

@$userID=$_SESSION['user'];
@$checkbox1=$_POST['Log'];
@$checkbox2=$_POST['Worktray'];
@$checkbox3=$_POST['Visual'];
@$checkbox4=$_POST['ChangePd']; 
@$checkbox5=$_POST['Logout'];
@$checkbox6=$_POST['ClientSearch'];
@$checkbox7=$_POST['StartAssessment'];
@$checkbox8=$_POST['Finalise'];
@$checkbox9=$_POST['Print'];
@$checkbox10=$_POST['Hcn'];
@$checkbox11=$_POST['Lcid'];
@$checkbox12=$_POST['Soscare'];
@$checkbox13=$_POST['Reassign'];
@$checkbox14=$_POST['Close'];

    $query="INSERT INTO enisatanswer (user_id,Log,Worktray,Visual,ChangePd,Logout,ClientSearch,StartAssessment,Finalise,Print,Hcn,Lcid,Soscare,Reassign,Close) VALUES 
    ('$userID', '$checkbox1', '$checkbox2','$checkbox3', '$checkbox4', '$checkbox5', '$checkbox6','$checkbox7', '$checkbox8','$checkbox9', '$checkbox10','$checkbox11', '$checkbox12', '$checkbox13', '$checkbox14')";  
    mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error() );
if($query==true)
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Your choices have inserted Successfully \n \n Please click on Display eNISAT Tutorials at the buttom of the page to view your videos ")</script>';  
   }  
else  
   {  
      echo'<script>alert("Failed To Insert")</script>';  
   }  
}  
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Welcome - <?php echo $userRow['username']; ?></title>
/<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
 <div id="left">
    <label>NHSCT eNISAT Tutorials</label>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
     <div id="content">
         Welcome <?php echo $userRow['forename']; ?>&nbsp;<a href="logout.php?logout">Sign Out</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<p align="center"><img src="title.jpeg" width="400"height="100" alt="title.jpeg">
<br>
<br>
<center>
<h2>Please select the tasks you require assistance with, before clicking DISPLAY ENISAT TUTORIALS:<h2>
<br>
<table align="center" height="0" width="70%" border="1" bgcolor = "white">
   <form  action="" method="post"

   <tr> 
      <td colspan="2">Tick each relevant box:</td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to login</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Log" value="1"></td>   
   <tr>  
      <td>How to manage your worktray</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Worktray" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your visual settings (Colours and text size)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Visual" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to change your own password on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ChangePd" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to logout of the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Logout" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to search for a client on the system</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="ClientSearch" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr> 
      <td>How to start an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="StartAssessment" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>
      <td>How to finalise an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Finalise" value="1"></td>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to print an assessment</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Print" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to create a client and referral manually through Find on H+C</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Hcn" value="1"></td>  
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from LCID (LCID Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Lcid" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to submit a referral from Soscare (Soscare Users only)</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Soscare" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to reassign a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Reassign" value="1"></td> 
   </tr>  
   <tr>  
      <td>How to close a referral on eNISAT</td>  
      <td><input type="checkbox" name="Close" value="1"></td>
   </tr> 
   <tr>  
      <td  <td><button name="submit" type="submit" onclick="window.location.href='eNISATVids.php'">Display eNISAT Tutorials</button></td>
</tr> 
</table>  
</div>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: side note: your code is VERY vulnerable for [SQL injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) - also: mysql_ functions are deprecated, use mysqli_ or pdo instead.

Comment: *.... causing issues when I am looking to pull information out again.* What Issues ?

Comment: I want to be able to associate each checkbox value to a row in another table to display video content but one thing at a time. This is only a prototype it wont be used in the public domain, I know these functions are depreciated but I just need to get this working in its existing format for now, as I have very little time left